# PC became slow without reason

Tags: windows-7, performance

My computer suddenly became slow two days ago, without any apparent reason. I thought it was a malware or something like that, so I formatted my computer, then reinstalled Windows 7 with the official CD, but it still is really slow!
I checked my HD with HD Tach, my memory with Memtest86+, and everything seems to be OK.
I ran an Hijackthis scan, and here is the log: http://pastebin.com/hXGzt6H8

If someone could help... I really don't understand why it is running so slowly! (the "missing files" in the hijackthis report are - from what I found - an error with HJT/Win7

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check your bios settings, be sure something did not inadvertently get changed, or just load bios defaults.

Comment: what kind of HD you have?

Comment: it's a Hitachi HDP725050GLAT80 3.5"

Answer (score 1):

Check your CPU temp & fans, if there is an overheating issue it may have throttled back the CPU

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely a hardware issue. Take off the computer casing and look inside for any loose hardware like ram sata or cards. Also if you have some card installed like a usb hub or something that you don't use remove it. Also check that you have nothing overheated and all the drivers installed.